# Excel VBA: Type mismatch when passing array

Tags: vba, excel

```
    myArray = Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")

    Call someSub(myArray)
```

...

```
    Sub someSub(ByRef myArray() as String) 'Error here
       'contents here
    End Sub
```

Type mismatch error on that second part -- what's causing it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out -- had to pass it as plain Variant

```
Sub someSub(myArray as Variant)
```

Answer (score 11):

Did you by any chance omit to use `Option Explicit` and then went on to not specify myArray's type ? That will make it a variant and you are saying `as String` which is indeed a type mismatch.

Comment: I don't have Option Explicit listed and I did not specify the type for the array (what you see when I assign A B C D E is when I define it). What is the better alternative/what does Explicit do?

Comment: Omitting `Option Explicit` allows you to create variables on the fly without explicitly declaring them. This opens up bug like this one. You should put `Option Explicit` at the top of every VBA project. There's even an option for this.

Comment: What is the correct way to define that array above with Option Explicit?

Answer (score 1):

Should really be using option explicit and then defining all of your variables as specific types.  In this case:

```
Option Explicit

Dim myArray(1 to 10) as String 'define the number of elements before you use it.
myArray(1) = 'A'
myArray(2) = 'B'
[etc etc]
```

It's a bit longer, but being type safe will make your code run faster and make it much easier to read.  It also prevents errors like the one you've run into...